# Using inline for a void function that takes no parameters

Tags: c++

Is there any potential performance gain in replacing

```
void foo(void){/*some statement*/}
```

with

```
inline void foo(void){/*some statement*/}
```

Comment: Just to clarify, are you asking whether the inline keyword will add anything? Because a function with the body in a header file is already inlined. Is your function in the header or in a cpp file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no function call and return overhead. It probably will prevent instruction cache from reloading. Compiler will be allowed to perform far more optimizations once function body will be inlined.

Some more explanations:

CPU will load instructions when it will see it needs them, so if function will be inlined then CPU can load whole code in one read causing less CPU stalls. But if this function is actually quite large and is not executed very often then inlining it might actually cause more harm because CPU will likely load more cache lines that it is necessary. Below is example:

```
if ( condition ) {
  // do some logic here
}
else {
  foo(); 
}
```

now if condition is mostly true, then its better if foo() is not inlined, if condition is mostly false, then its better if it is inlined. So to make your code more cache friendly you should actually find a most common path of execution and make it work with as little if-s and possibly little function calls.

Function call overhead in this case is caused by the need to save registers on the stack (how many depends on actuall code), incrementing stack pointer, and jumping to funciton code. After function is done CPU needs to restore stack and registers to its previous state. This is obviously a lot of work especially if function is called inside tight loop.

Finally its important to remember that inline is only a hint to compiler. As a programmer you have knowledge of how your code is executed, and you should use this knowledge to structure your code to make it more cache friendly.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the cache. IMHO, that's the biggest performance problem

Comment: Could you explain the cache problem and why function call has no overhead?

Answer (score 1):

Yes (apart from the small but non-zero cost of the call): the optimiser might be able to do more to optimise the inlined code than it could with a function call.

Answer (score 1):

Not-inlined function call incurs some minor penality even if you do not pass any arguments back and forth. For example, the address where the function should return after finishing its execution needs to be stored somewhere.

If I were you, I would make no particular distinction between void-void functions and other type of functions when deciding if to `inline` it or not. There are other more significant aspects which decide if `inline` is helpful or not, for example:

- frequency of the calls (higher number favors inlining)
- size of the function (bigger size favors not inlining)

Comment: "the address where the function should return after finishing its execution needs to be stored somewhere": that's a good point.

Answer (score 1):

The overhead cost of a function call -- creating a stack for the function, pushing the arguments to the stack, managing return value from the stack, and deleting the stack -- are avoided when you have an inline function. That would improve performance.

In your case, you don't have any input arguments and a return value. So the cost of a function call will be reduced a little bit. It will be still more expensive than an inline function.

Answer (score 1):

`inline` is completely orthogonal to `parameter` and `return` type.